# Get Solr documents that include only a specific set of values

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a Solr collection with a multiValued field "myField". I want to fetch documents where myField contains values from a specific set, and nothing else.

So for example, from the following set of documents:

```
{ "title": "Doc 1", "myField": ["A", "B"] },
{ "title": "Doc 2", "myField": ["A", "C"] },
{ "title": "Doc 3", "myField": ["A"] }
```

I want to fetch the documents where all the values in myField are within the set ("A", "B"), which means "Doc 1" and "Doc 3", but *not* "Doc 2" because "Doc 2" also has "C" in myField.

Currently I'm getting the results I want by excluding documents where myField contains specific values. I.e. in this case: `-myField:C`

This problem with this approach is that it only works when all the values that need to be excluded are known ahead of time. Is there a way to flip this logic around so that I can query for only specific values to be included instead?

Comment: I'm not that experienced with Solr, but from looking at the documentation it seems like one way to solve this might be to use custom field analyzers?